# One point compactification and extension of a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

If $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism, the statement goes like this: $h$ extends to a unique homeomorphism $\hat{h}:S^n \to S^n$, because $S^n$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this statement obvious? What are the underlying mechanisms that allow us to conclude it? Is it related to the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma)?

Comment: It follows from the definition of the neighborhoods of the added point $\infty$. Note that $h$ must map compacts to compacts and preimages of compacts are compacts.

Answer (score 1):

There is really one way to do this, so it is quite unclear where you got stuck. (Which you should mention in the post.) 
The extension must map the extra point to itself. Now check the definition of continuity, that is, every open set must have an open pre-image. 
Make a case disctinction, as there are two essentially different types of open sets in the compactification (either it contains the extra point or it does not). 
Which part is unclear?